# Attempting to build Dynamic Array from scratch: Segmentation Fault when using delete[] in append function

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to build a C++ vector from scratch for an assignment, but I've been struggling all day. My append function is broken. At first it would take no string input, but I've gotten it to append one string to the dynamic list. However, when I attempt to append a second string to the list, the temp array is appended with that string, but when I go to delete the existing data attribute array that second time (the previous temp array), I get a segmentation fault. I've included a lot of print statements to pinpoint this.

I have tried instantiating a block of objects using placement new since strings are objects. Here is the DynamicList class.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DynamicList.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
 
//Constructor
template<typename T>
DynamicList<T>::DynamicList(){
        size = 0;
        data = new T[size];
}
 
//Destructor
template<typename T>
DynamicList<T>::~DynamicList(){
        std::cout << "Deleting array of size: " << getSize() << std::endl;
        delete[] data;
 
}
 
//Overloading operators
template<typename T>
DynamicList<T> DynamicList<T>::operator=(DynamicList<T>& obj){
        obj.size = size;
        std::copy(data, data + size, obj.data);
}
template<typename T>
bool DynamicList<T>::operator==(DynamicList<T>& obj){
        if(size != obj.size){
                return false;
        }
        else{
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                        if(obj.data[i] != data[i]){
                                return false;
                        }
                }
                return true;
        }
 
}
 
template<typename T>
bool DynamicList<T>::operator!=(DynamicList<T>& obj){
        return !(DynamicList<T>::operator==(obj));
}
 
template<typename T>
T DynamicList<T>::operator[](int index){
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if(i == index){
                        return data[i];
                }
        }
}
//Returns the size of the list
template<typename T>
int DynamicList<T>::getSize(){
        return size;
}
//Add element to the end of list.
template<typename T>
bool DynamicList<T>::append(T item){
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
 
        T* temp = static_cast<T*>(new T(sizeof(T) * (size + 1), alignof(T)));
        if(size > 1){
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                        T* somePtr = new (&temp[i]) T;
                        *somePtr = data[i];
                }
        }
        T* itemPtr = new (&temp[size]) T;
        *itemPtr = item;
        std::cout << "Ptr made in array slot.\n";
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        size++;
        std::cout << "Size increased.\n";
 
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
        std::cout << "AAAAAA\n";
        delete[] data;
        std::cout << "BBBBB\n";
        data = temp;
        std::cout << data[size - 1] << std::endl;
        return true;
}
```

Here is the header file for DynamicList:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef DYNAMICLIST_H
#define DYNAMICLIST_H

template<typename T>
class DynamicList{

        private:
                int size;
                T* data;
        public:
                //constructor
                DynamicList();
                //destructor
                ~DynamicList();
                //Operator overloaders
                DynamicList operator=(DynamicList& obj);
                bool operator==(DynamicList& obj);
                bool operator!=(DynamicList& obj);
                T operator[](int index);
                //Returns the size of the data array
                int getSize();
                //Add an item to the end of the list
                bool append(T item);
                //Remove an item at an index
                bool remove(int index);
};

#endif
```

Here is the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DynamicList.hpp"
#include "DynamicList.cpp"

int main(){

        DynamicList<std::string> stringList;

        stringList.append("test");
        stringList.append("test2");

        return 0;
}
```

Here is the makefile:

```
all: DynamicList.hpp DynamicList.cpp main.cpp
        g++ -c DynamicList.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp
        g++ DynamicList.o main.o -o exec

run: all
        ./exec

clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm -f exec
```

Here is the error:

```
./exec
0x55c688824eb8
test
Ptr made in array slot.
0x55c6888252f0
Size increased.
0x55c688824eb8
AAAAAA
BBBBB
test
0x55c6888252f0
test2
Ptr made in array slot.
0x55c688824eb0
Size increased.
0x55c6888252f0
AAAAAA
make: *** [makefile:8: run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: *My append function is broken* -- Please post a [mcve].  We have no idea what the state of `data` is when you call this function.  Just because this is where your code crashes doesn't mean this is where the problem originated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wakarimashita

Comment: The constructor creates the array with array `new[]`, but the append function uses object `new` instead. Deleting objects created with object `new` using array `delete[]` or vice versa is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your class violates the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Where is your user-defined copy constructor?  In addition to that, your `operator=` leaks memory since it fails to delete the old memory from the object.

Comment: @mcendu So how do I destroy arrays not created with ```new[]``` but with object ```new```? I tried deleting the array using just ```delete``` after the size is at 3 and above (after first append and size increment when it becomes an array created with object ```new```), but that also gave me a segmentation fault.

Comment: @JohnSmith You should fix the `new` in `append` to use `new[]` instead. You shouldn't hack elsewhere,

Comment: Arthur O'Dwyer explains how to program a "not-so-naive" vector class—and supplies source code—in this talk from CppCon 2019: [“Back to Basics: RAII and the Rule of Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ). You don't have to implement the entire interface of `std::vector`, just enough to complete your assignment. Here is the [cheat sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ&t=40m58s).

Comment: @mcendu Thanks. You can close the question now. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @JohnSmith Posted (attempt) as answer.

Comment: _Side note:_ These days, many—and perhaps, most—class templates have their functions defined within the class (i.e., in the header file). One big advantage is readability, but an even more important one is optimization. Functions that are defined within a class can be inlined by the compiler. Unless your instructor requires you to split your class template into .`h` and `.cpp` files, I would try putting the whole thing in the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor creates the array with array `new[]`, but the append function uses object `new` instead. Deleting objects created with object `new` using array `delete[]` or vice versa is undefined behavior.

You should replace the object `new` in `append` with array `new[]`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool DynamicList<T>::append(T item) {
        T* temp = new T[size + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                temp[i] = data[i];
        }
        temp[size] = item;
        size++;
 
        delete[] data;
        data = temp;
        return true;
}
```